# How to write a program that consistently displays text, has the functions play, pause, next, previous?

Tags: ios, swift

I make a text player which subsequently displays the phrase in one language after some time, an English translation with the phrase playing out loud using mp3. There are buttons play, pause, next, previous.

I wrote the code, there are some bugs in it:

```
class Sentence: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var rus: String
    var eng: String
    var link: String

    init(id: Int, rus: String, eng: String, link: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.rus = rus
        self.eng = eng
        self.link = link
    }
}

class WordsViewController: UIViewController {

    var sentences: [Sentence] = [Sentence]()
    var isPlayTouch = false
    var isIncrement = false
    var speed: Double = 1.5
    var position: Int = 0

    @objc func playAction() {
        self.isPlayTouch = true
        if sentences.count > 0 {

            let duration = self.getDurationAudio(link: self.sentences[self.position].link)

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                if self.isPlayTouch {
                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: duration * self.speed)
                    if self.isPlayTouch {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.playSound()
                            self.wordsView.sentence.text = self.sentences[self.position].eng
                            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                                if self.isPlayTouch {
                                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: duration)
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        if self.isPlayTouch {
                                            if self.position == self.sentences.count - 1 {
                                                self.pauseAction()
                                                if !self.isIncrement {
                                                    self.isIncrement = true
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                if self.isPlayTouch {
                                                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
                                                    if self.isPlayTouch {
                                                        self.position = self.position + 1
                                                        self.setText()
                                                        if self.isPlayTouch {
                                                            self.playAction()
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

- After pressing the pause button for the delay time, and immediately pressing the playlist, two phrases are played at once, this is due to checking on the isPlayTouch variable

Tell me how to write this functionality?

Comment: 15 `}` after each other is horrendous. Code like that is very hard to read and understand (and fix). I would rewrite the code without any use of DispatchQueue until I got it working.

Comment: This is part of the code. Just copy will not work